# How can I invoke an SQLAlchemy query with limit of 1?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have code like this:

```
thing = thing.query.filter_by(id=thing_id).limit(1).all()[0]
```

`all()[0]` feels a bit messy and redundant in the `limit(1)` case. Is there a more terse (and/or otherwise optimal) way to achieve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Jwodder's answer will, indeed, return the first result as a scalar, but SQLAlchemy provides a couple other functions that may better suit your needs, so I have listed and explained all of them:

`first()` applies a limit of one and returns the first result as a scalar, or `None` if no row is returned. [first()](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/tutorial.html#returning-lists-and-scalars:%7E:text=Query.first()%20applies%20a%20limit%20of%20one%20and%20returns%20the%20first%20result%20as%20a%20scalar%3A)

`one()` fully fetches all rows, and if not exactly one object identity or composite row is present in the result, raises an error. [one()](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/tutorial.html#returning-lists-and-scalars:%7E:text=Query.one()%20fully%20fetches%20all%20rows%2C%20and%20if%20not%20exactly%20one%20object%20identity%20or%20composite%20row%20is%20present%20in%20the%20result%2C%20raises%20an%20error)

`one_or_none()` will essentially do a `one()`, but instead of erroring out will return `None` if no rows are returned.  This will still error out if more than one rows is returned.

The documentation for all of these can be found here: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html

Answer (score 15):

There's [`first()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/tutorial.html#returning-lists-and-scalars):

> `first()` applies a limit of one and returns the first result as a scalar

Thus:

```
thing = thing.query.filter_by(id=thing_id).first()
```

Answer (score 4):

First of all, agree and support other answers.

However, it looks like that your queries are for the `primary key` column. If this is the case, the most straightforward way of making such a query would be to simply call [`get()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.get):

```
thing = Thing.query.get(thing_id)
```

Comment: Nice! I actually want to do this: `Thing.query.with_entities(Thing.foo).filter_by(id=thing_id).limit(1).all().[0]`, which seems to not be possible with `.get()`

Comment: Indeed, `get` only works on the object itself and only for a primary key.

Answer (score 1):

SQLAlchemy core provides a [.limit(1) operator](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/tutorial.html#ordering-grouping-limiting-offset-ing) on a query.