# SQLAlchemy limit(1) with first()

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I observed a query that someone else wrote that looks something like this...

```
conn.execute(
    foo.select()
    .where(foo.c.type == type).limit(1)).first()
```

I assumed `first()` returned the first case it found without getting all of the results therefore `limit(1)` is not needed.

Does having `limit(1)` actually make the query faster or provide any benefit?

Comment: Let's go to the [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Query.first): "first() applies a limit of one within the generated SQL." No, it doesn't make the query faster. However, `first()` returns a single result while `limit()` returns a sequence of results. So I suppose the benefit of `first()` is that you don't need to use `next()` or `[0]` to access the result. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37146073/how-can-i-invoke-an-sqlalchemy-query-with-limit-of-1 for more discussion. Using just `first()` accomplishes the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

I am facing the same issue and the answer in the comment refers to SQLA version <= 1.3:

```py
from sqlalchemy.orm import Query

Query(Feature.id).with_session(db_session()).first()
```

produces the following query:

```sql
SELECT features.id AS features_id FROM features LIMIT %(param_1)s
```

But for SQLA >= 1.4 (in newer syntax):

```py
from sqlalchemy import select

db_session.execute(select(Feature.id)).first()
```

it will produce the following query:

```sql
SELECT features.id FROM features
```

And this behavior is well-documented: [in a note](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.CursorResult.first)

> Additionally, in contrast to the behavior of the legacy ORM Query.first() method, **no limit is applied** to the SQL query which was invoked to produce this Result; for a DBAPI driver that buffers results in memory before yielding rows, all rows will be sent to the Python process and all but the first row will be discarded.